# Enviar datos desde C# a Javascript para mostrar en Label

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Espero me ayuden con esto,  quiero hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `select` Impuesto lo traigo desde la base de datos con el siguiente código:

```
private void llenaImpuestos()
{
    txtImpuestos.DataSource = objNegocio.cbImpuestos();
    txtImpuestos.DataTextField = "NOM_IMPUESTO";
    txtImpuestos.DataValueField = "ID_IMPUESTO";
    txtImpuestos.DataBind();
}
```

`txtImpuesto` es el `select` donde muestro los impuestos. Quisiera mostrar entre Impuestos y Precio Final el monto del impuesto asociado (%) y que cada vez que cambie el valor del `select`, se muestre el valor del impuesto correspondiente para poder hacer los cálculos en el Precio Final.

Creo que una forma es enviando los datos recibidos (`DataTable`) a una `List<>`, y estos pasárselos a un `Array` en JavaScript para que los muestre en el `Label`.

Nota, lo programo en ncapas, no MVC.

Agradezco el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea buena opcion poner datos en un array de javascript, sino obtener el dato especifico que necesitas invocando al servidor por medio de `ajax`

Si usas `asp.net` y te animas con `jquery` podrias usar ua llamada a un `WebMethod` por medio de `$.ajax`

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

analiza como define en el cliente

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
    data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

y en el servidor

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

podrias enviar la selecion del combo como valor para filtrar los datos en el servidor y obtener el valor simple que quieres mostrar en el textbox en lugar de tener todo un array en el cliente

Analiza esta tecnico te va a resultar mucho mas practica en tu desarrollo